# How to display fetched result inside php form?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am a PHP MYSQL beginner! trying to get the id (primary key) value of a row and update its corresponding values in a database. My search results are working perfecting and am getting redirected to my update form page, where in which i wanted to display the fetched result, so that i can edit the result and update the values.

My PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'db_alternate2.php';
session_start();

try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
if( isset($_GET['edit']) )
{
$id = $_GET['edit'];  
$res= "SELECT * FROM staff_db WHERE staff_id='$id'";

$r = $conn->query($res);
$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if( isset($_POST['new_staf_id']) && isset($_POST['new_staf_name']) && isset($_POST['new_staf_acc']) && isset($_POST['new_staf_bnkaddrs']) )
{
 $staf_id = $_POST['new_staf_id'];
 $staf_name = $_POST['new_staf_name'];
 $staf_acc = $_POST['new_staf_acc'];
 $staf_bnkaddrs = $_POST['new_staf_bnkaddrs'];
 $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE staff_db SET staff_id='$staf_id' staff_name='$staf_name' staff_acc='$staf_acc' staff_bnkaddrs='$staf_bnkaddrs' WHERE sl_no ='$id'");
 $sql->execute();
 $result1 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=staff_update.php'>";
 }
 } catch (PDOException $pe) {
 die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
 }
 ?> .
```

My HTML

```
  <form class="" style="right:10px !important;" action="staff_db.php" method="post">

    <div class="main-left" style="width:38% !important; margin-left:100px;">
      <p>Staff ID:</p> <input type="text" name="staf_id" value="______"/>
      <p>Name:</p> <input type="text" name="staf_name" value="______"/>
    </div>

    <div class="main-right" style="width:38% !important; margin-right:100px;">
      <p>Account no:</p> <input type="text" name="staf_acc" value="______"/>
      <p>Bank Address:</p> <input type="text" name="staf_bnkaddrs" value="______"/>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-centre" style="padding-top:50px; ">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </div>

  </form>
```

I know this is a simple question, but guide me here! how to display the PDO fetched results inside the **value="______"** of form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the PHP PDO manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just few modifications in your code

```html
if( isset($_GET['edit']) )
{
$id = $_GET['edit'];  
$res= "SELECT * FROM staff_db WHERE staff_id='$id'";

$r = $conn->query($res);
$r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $r->fetch();
}
```

and few modification in your form to put value

```html
<input type="text" name="staf_name" value=<?php echo $result["staff_name"]; ?>/>
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot, it worked! but then, my code has another error -- _Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object_ -- for the line **$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);**. Is there a problem with my query statement **$sql**.....?

Comment: it is better if you use prepare statement some thing like this : $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute(); 
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: I tried that statement @kevin, but my update function isn't working. The submitted value is not getting updated to my database table, but It perfectly returns to my redirect page without showing any error. I have edited my above PHP code.. Please tell me where i am going wrong!